# How can I increase TTL expiresAfterSeconds time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am creating a simple app and I have my model like this

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const urlSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    originalUrl: { type: String, required: true },
    longUrl: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    shortUrl: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    click: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export const Url = mongoose.model("Url", urlSchema);
```

So the problem now is, when an instance of this model in a document is created I figured there's a TTL index which has an `expiresAfterSeconds: 120` set and the document basically auto deletes after two minutes and in as much as I want the document to delete after a specific time, more like 3 days, all the documents created deletes after 2 minutes, I realized having the `{timestaps: true}` makes this happen, when I get rid of it, the documents stays as it is (the document does not auto delete). I'm wondering why this is happening and is there a way to increase the time `expiresAfterSeconds` to about 3 days or more or if there is a way to do it in some other ways and also for future reasons how to completely disallow the `expireAfterSeconds: 120` to be set even when the `{timestanps: true}` is set because I may need the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields. I am fairly new to mongoose and mongodb in general so I'll appreciate if anyone can help me with this and also explain why this is happening and how I can better avoid this next time.

also when I run my `db.urls.getIndexes()` in mongo shell, this is what returns, to help you better understand what it is I'm going through haha :

```
[
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { longUrl: 1 },
    name: 'longUrl_1',
    background: true,
    unique: true
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { shortUrl: 1 },
    name: 'shortUrl_1',
    background: true,
    unique: true
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { createdAt: 1 },
    name: 'createdAt_1',
    background: true,
    expireAfterSeconds: 120
  }
]
```

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/#change-the-expireafterseconds-value-for-a-ttl-index

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your schema

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const urlSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
originalUrl: { type: String, required: true },
longUrl: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
shortUrl: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
click: {
  type: Number,
  default: 0,
 },
 createdAt: { type: Date, expires: "3d", default: Date.now },
},
{ timestamps: { createdAt: false, updatedAt: true } }
);

urlSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 });

export const Url = mongoose.model("Url", urlSchema);
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).